# Why maximum integer number multiplication gives 1 as result

Tags: java, int

I think much explanation is not required, why below calculation gives result as 1?

```
int a = 2147483647;
int b = 2147483647;

int c = a * b;
long d = a * b;
double e = a * b;

System.out.println(c);  //1
System.out.println(d);  //1
System.out.println(e);  //1.0
```

Comment: According to you, what should it give and why?

Comment: According to normal calculation,like  3*2=6,it has to give 2147483647*2147483647 result...ofcourse int can't take that much but why 1??

Comment: All 3 statements will perform the multiplication using `int` math, not `long` or `double`. The widening conversion to `long` and `double` happens *after* the multiplication.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The binary representation of the integer number 2147483647 is as following:

```
01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

Multiplying this with itself results in the number 4611686014132420609 whose binary representation is:

```
00111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

This is too large for the `int` type which has only 32 bits. The multiplication of `a * b` is done as an integer multiplication only, regardless of the variable's type to which the result is assigned (which might do a widening conversion, but only after the multiplication).

So, the result simply cuts off all bits that do not fit into the 32 bits, leaving only the following result:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

And this simply is the value 1.

If you want keep the information, you must do the multiplication with the `long` type which has 64 bits:

```
long a = 2147483647;
long b = 2147483647;
long mult = a * b;

System.out.println((int) mult);     // 1
System.out.println(mult);           // 4611686014132420609
System.out.println((double) mult);  // 4.6116860141324206E18
```

If you need more bits for a calculation you might consider [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) (for integral numbers) or [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) (for decmial numbers).

Answer (score 5):

2147483647 * 2147483647 = 4611686014132420609

Which in Hexa = ‭3FFFFFFF 00000001‬, after truncation only 00000001 remains which represents 1.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the reason that the three attempts all give the same answer is that they are all performing 32 bit multiplications and the multiplication overflows, resulting in "loss of information".  The overflow / loss of information happens *before* the value of the RHS<sup>1</sup> expression is assigned to the variable on the LHS.

In the 2nd and 3rd case you could cause the expression to be evaluated using 64 bit or floating point:

```
int c = a * b;
long d = ((long) a) * b;
double e = ((double) a) * b;
```

and you would not get overflow.

As to why you get overflow in the 32 bit case, that is simple.  The result is larger than 32 bits.  The other answers explain why the answer is `1`.

Just for fun, here is an informal proof.

Assume that we are talking about a modular number system with numbers in the range 2<sup>N-1</sup> to 2<sup>N-1</sup> - 1.  In such a number system, X * 2<sup>N</sup> maps to zero ... for all integers X.

If we multiply the max value by itself we get

> (2<sup>N-1</sup> - 1) * (2<sup>N-1</sup> - 1)
>
> -> 2<sup>2N-2</sup> - 2 * 2<sup>N-1</sup> + 1
>
> -> 2<sup>2N-2</sup> - 2<sup>N</sup> + 1

Now map that into the original range:

> 2<sup>2N-2</sup> maps to 0
>
> 2<sup>N</sup> maps 0
>
> 1 maps to 1
>
> 0 + 0 + 0 -> 1

---

<sup>1 - LHS == left hand side, RHS == right hand side.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is simply the result of integer overflow, which follows this rule:

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE
```

One way to see what is happening is to contrive Java's `int` type as ranging from `-7` to `7`, with the same rule still applying.  Let's see what happens when we multiply `7*7`:

```
 7 + 7 = 14 -> -2   (7 x 2)
-2 + 7 = 5          (7 x 3)
 5 + 7 = 12 -> -4   (7 x 4)
-4 + 7 = 3          (7 x 5)
 3 + 7 = 10 -> -6   (7 x 6)
-6 + 7 = 1          (7 x 7, one is leftover)
```

The same thing is happening in your code, with `2147483647` overflowing according to:

```
2147483647 + 1 = -2147483648
```

Answer (score 0):

**Because:**

2147483647 * 2147483647 = 4611686014132420609

> Integer capacity = 4294967295

4611686014132420609 % 4294967295 = 1

Answer (score -2):

integer has only 3 byte memory allocation as well as double has 8 byte memory allocation your multiplication is so large than its give only starting which has (0000 0001)2 = 1